# React.js -- Bootstrap / Reactstrap -- z-index does not work on Carousel

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, carousel, z-index, reactstrap

I want my fixed navbar that stays on the top of the page to display over everything as I scroll down through the page, but when I scroll down the Carousel ends up on top of the navbar.

I have tried to give a z-index: 0 with an !important tag to the carousel, and z-index: 1 to the nav bar but that didn't do the trick. There is a photo attached to show the problem I am talking about.

[image: I want the navbar to display on top of the carousel]

Comment: I think images have high z-index value. Increase the z-index of navbar

Comment: I had put the z-index on the navbar container, not the actual navbar. That's why it wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give the zindex of fixed navbar some higher value like
`z-index: 1090`

I wrap the Navbar in a sticky div:-

```
<div className="sticky-top" style={{ zIndex: 1090 }}>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
</div>
```

BTW I use react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at my **header CSS properties**. My header has a z-index: 1. Fiasco.
Change it to 1090. It will help you.

Check all elements what was overflow by the gallery. **Check them all!!!** (z-indexes)!